# How I can add signals to an array of toolbuttons on a toolbar? mono gtk#

Tags: mono, gtk, monodevelop, gtk#

I create a group of buttons on the toolbar, with this code

```
ToolButton [] botones = new ToolButton[3];

    for (int y = 0; y < botones.Length; y++) 
    {
        botones [y] = new ToolButton (Stock.Add);
        botones [y].Label = "menu" + y;
        toolbar1.Insert(botones [y],toolbar1.NItems);


    }
    ShowAll ();
```

How I can add the signals to each button, so when I cliked, I get the  label of each button in the toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a handler to the Clicked event for each of the tool buttons.

```
botones [y].Clicked += (o, args) => {
    ToolButton b = o as ToolButton;
    if (b != null)
        Console.WriteLine ("{0} was press", b.Label);
};
```

I also tried the ButtonPressEvent and ButtonReleaseEvent but neither of those were thrown when the tool button was clicked.

Comment: ButtonPressEvent and ButtonReleaseEvent are low-level input events. You don't want to watch for them unless you're doing custom input handling on, say, a GtkDrawingArea. Clicked is the correct event here.